# Using prepared MySQLi statements to produce associative array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've read a few related questions to this, but in each case I've been unable to get their code to work in my context.

Following some injection attempts, I am trying to implement prepared statements into my site, while changing as little code as possible. Importantly, I want the responses to my `SELECT` queries to by outputted as associative arrays: e.g. `$row['name']`.

Here is an example of code that I have right now (without preprepared statements):

```
// Create connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'seatingplan');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

// Get class name

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `class` 
    WHERE `userid` = '$userid'
    AND `classid` = '$classid'  
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $classname =  $row['classname'] ;
}
```

Is there a straightforward way of adapting this for prepared statements? Based on other questions, this is as far as I've got (but it doesn't work - it only returns 1 for each row, rather than the actual variable):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT *
    FROM `class` 
    WHERE `userid` = ?
    AND `classid` = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $userid, $classid);

$result = $stmt->execute(); 

$stmt->store_result(); 

while($data = $stmt->fetch()){ 

        echo $data ;
}
```

Comment: `echo $data ;` there's no array. see the manual on `fetch()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php and didn't select the rows you want to echo. You also need to bind the result. `bind_result()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the array and use it for example in your code:

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT *
    FROM `class` 
    WHERE `userid` = ?
    AND `classid` = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $userid, $classid);

$stmt->execute(); 

$result=$stmt->get_result(); 
$row= array();
$i=0;
         while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
                $row[$i]['name']=$data['name'];
                $i++;
        }
echo $row;
```

Comment: Thank you, however using that code I get: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()`